# How to use android:Layout_marginLeft dynamically in Android for TextView

Tags: android

I am creating a TextView dynamically from Activity. I created 2 Textviews and I want to maintain some gap between 2 TextViews. How can this be achieved through code rather than from XML. Normally in XML we use android:layout_marginLeft/Right tag to maintain gap between 2 TextViews. How can this be achieved through code? 
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the layout you are using. This example places a RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutParent;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams margin = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
margin.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 7); //7px bottom margin

//get or create the linear and the relative layouts

...

// Add view with its margins
linearLayoutParent.addView(relativeLayout, margin);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```